# Web Deploy (MSDeploy) 3.6 replace rule to rename a file

Tags: windows, replace, command-line, msdeploy, webdeploy

I'm using msdeploy on the command-line to deploy a windows service using the `sync` verb against `dirPath` source and destination providers. So far so good.

My project's build assets have per-environment config files, and during deploy to a particular environment I want to rename the targeted environment's config file to the default config file name using a replace rule, but no matter how I engineer my replace rule nothing seems to get me the results I want. I've tried with a number of different configurations of the rule with no luck but the one that seems the most logical is this one:

```
-replace:objectName=filePath,scopeAttributeName=path,scopeAttributeValue=Service\.Dev\.exe\.config,match=Service\.Dev\.exe\.config,replace=Service.exe.config
```

If I deploy without the replace rule both `Service.Dev.exe.config` and `Service.exe.config` are deployed with the expected respective content. Once I add the replace rule above I get just `Service.exe.config` and it's got the content of that file from the source, not the content of `Service.Dev.exe.config` as I am hoping for. If I swap the specifications of the `match` and `replace` components (and change regexp <-> plain text accordingly) to arrive at:

```
-replace:objectName=filePath,scopeAttributeName=path,scopeAttributeValue=Service\.Dev\.exe\.config,match=Service\.exe\.config,replace=Service.Dev.exe.config
```

I just get `Service.Dev.exe.config` with the content of `Service.exe.config` and no `Service.exe.config` in the destination.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but what is it?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your question but I think its a better solution to your root problem.

The real issue here is config management for different environments.  Many developers create different configs for each environment like you do.  This approach requires a lot of duplication across your different config files which can easily get out of sync.

The best approach I've found for managing configuration across different environments is WebDeploy Parameterization.  It is similar to config transforms in that you have a single base config file that is tweaked, so there is far less duplication.  Parameterization however is preferred because it applies the changes at deploy time instead of build time.  We use this for 50+ applications with great success.

Here is a blog post with more details - http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2014/09/08/parameterizationpreview-visual-studio-extension/

Answer (score -1):

The match and replace should swap

`match=Service.Dev.exe.config,replace=Service\.exe\.config`

Comment: If you'd read my post carefully you'd note that I tried it with those elements in both combinations. If I'm misunderstanding what you mean then if you can clarify perhaps I'll understand better.